# What is the requirement for the existence of independence in the complement of conditional independence

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

Given two events A & B which are independent on an event C conditionally, What is the requirement for A&B to to be independent on C's complement.

I mean when,

[image]

to be the below,

[image]

Is below the requirement,

[image]

Am I correct ?